# python list split error for ec2metadata

Tags: python

I want to split the output obtained in **list1** which is this

['ami-id: ami-f173cc91', 'ami-launch-index: 0', 'ami-manifest-path: (unknown)', 'ancestor-ami-ids: not available']

**into**

['ami-id':ami-f173cc91,'ami-launch-index':0,'ami-manifest-path':(unknown),'ancestor-ami-ids':not available]

so that I can construct a table in html

Here is the program

```
import subprocess
output=subprocess.check_output("ec2-metadata")
mystring=output.replace('root: /dev/xvda','')
list1= [y for y in (x.strip() for x in mystring.splitlines()) if y]
list2={k:v for k,v in (x.split(':') for x in list1)}
```

But I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 7, in <module>
    list2={k:v for k,v in (x.split(':') for x in list1)}
  File "hello.py", line 7, in <dictcomp>
    list2={k:v for k,v in (x.split(':') for x in list1)}
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I guess I should I have given the complete list, here it is

```
['ami-id: ami-f173cc91', 'ami-launch-index: 0', 'ami-manifest-path: (unknown)', 'ancestor-ami-ids: not available', 'ami: /dev/xvda', 'instance-id: i-003d85b896d419cbc', 'instance-type: t2.micro', 'local-hostname: ip-172-31-16-4.us-west-2.compute.internal', 'local-ipv4: 172.31.16.4', 'kernel-id: not available', 'placement: us-west-2a', 'product-codes: not available', 'public-hostname: ec2-52-35-60-43.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com', 'public-ipv4: 52.35.60.43', 'keyname:webserverami', 'index:0', 'format:openssh-key', 'key:(begins from next line)', 'ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCeOeaZM9wHX6HcfUL3f42vuLX0oLec4QmgqIppR3PJ880HQ8ImYkkLbgtK74eQ97Gn76sLhecG3MpQN5R8uXD13eaTSdu2ZwE11YGeIfkS+wR3UhCtPwx5QzyNz84JfOLdUd8EBDwTk0wZCucno4xwt+UaEAzKfnEaPYpYxxl/X2uT+Rl0JqukXP/Wip1OoHWgKrkgZxNiHb4hM44Ele3cH1OZhO8+HGZYys69NBuxe2HvW2kFIesEMrCWQwAcEkD+j+ddFekeTI5KDuHPj0tXbntw7164ZZmlGYKSStv+36xntcrDi6/k+B84niASP6iOrFQG4tRi1RqKG3JRPixT webserverami', 'ramdisk-id: not available', 'reservation-id: r-03b8863dc56eb4b3f', 'security-groups: launch-wizard-15', 'user-data: not available']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
list1 = ['ami-id: ami-f173cc91', 'ami-launch-index: 0', 'ami-manifest-path: (unknown)', 'ancestor-ami-ids: not available']`
```

and expected output be

```
{'ami-manifest-path': '(unknown)', 'ami-launch-index': '0', 'ancestor-ami-ids': 'not available', 'ami-id': 'ami-f173cc91'}
```

Then just do this:

```
list2 = {z[0]: z[1].strip() for z in list(map(lambda i: i.split(":"), list1))}
```

list2 is your expected response.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work.I get the following error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 9, in <module>
    list2={z[0]:z[1].strip() for z in list(map(lambda i:i.split(":"),list1))}
  File "hello.py", line 9, in <dictcomp>
    list2={z[0]:z[1].strip() for z in list(map(lambda i:i.split(":"),list1))}
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Its working fine for me for the example you shared:
`['ami-id: ami-f173cc91', 'ami-launch-index: 0', 'ami-manifest-path: (unknown)', 'ancestor-ami-ids: not available']`
I am using python3.4.3

Comment: Can you share some more list1 examples?

Comment: The `ssh-rsa...` value(as mentioned by you in helloV's comment) was not present in your above example dict, that's why the code is failing

Comment: So, any idea how to do it, for this type of list?